# How to convert lifetime of boxed reference without allocating a new box?

Tags: rust

### Context

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1f50896fc89fa4535da952a2d8c5399c), This works:

```
fn get_owned_box_working<'a>(b: Box<&'a i32>) -> Box<&'static i32> {
    Box::new(&42)
}
```

but this doesn't:

```rust
fn get_owned_box_broken<'a>(b: Box<&'a i32>) -> Box<&'static i32> {
    *b = &42;
    b
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     b
  |     ^ lifetime mismatch
  |
  = note: expected struct `Box<&'static i32>`
             found struct `Box<&'a i32>`
note: the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
 --> src/lib.rs:1:25
  |
1 | fn get_owned_box_broken<'a>(b: Box<&'a i32>) -> Box<&'static i32> {
  |                         ^^
  = note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime
```

### Question

- How come the compiler can't update the lifetime of the existing box from `'a` -> `'static` when I mutate it?
- Is there some way to get this to work without the extra allocation from creating a new box?

Comment: `Box<Cow<'static, str>>` what is this monstrosity, don't, that defeat the very purpose of CoW xd

Comment: @Stargateur LOL this was me trying to minimally reproduce what I'm actually running into. I wouldn't actually write this code. I'm mostly just interested in the fact that the lifetime inside the box doesn't change without a new box being allocated

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Stargateur. I was working with `Cow` types hence the monstrosity, but now with the `i32` I look sane. The only issue is now the answer is wrong so probably need to edit that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come the compiler can't update the lifetime of the existing box from `'a` -> `'static` when I mutate it?

From the compiler point of view, you cannot "update" the value from using `'a` to using `'static`. You are assigning to it, but the type stays the same. Then later you're trying to convert from `Box<&'a i32>` to `Box<&'static i32>`, and it rightfully bails.

> Is there some way to get this to work without the extra allocation from creating a new box?

Yes, but only using `unsafe`: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eed2ed5fe6e93a21347e591cb33c882c)

```rust
fn get_owned_box_broken<'a>(s: Box<&'a i32>) -> Box<&'static i32> {
    unsafe {
        let s = Box::into_raw(s);
        let s = s.cast::<&'static i32>();
        s.write(&42);
        Box::from_raw(s)
    }
}
```

However, think carefully if you need that: it is likely you can afford an allocation.

Comment: Ok I won't actually do this. I was just really curious about if lifetimes could change through assignment and I see the answer is no

Comment: should a transmute be more ... simple ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f58d45a83659adb9e1a8205f4a27e94b

Comment: @Stargateur I don't like to transmute when I can do pointer casts, but yes, it would work.

Comment: @Stargateur Besides, you still need `ptr::read()` and `ptr::write()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because lifetime is part of the *type*.

So when you assigning `*b = &42;`, your left part has type `&'a i32` and right part has type `&'static i32`. Bigger lifetime can be coerced to smaller one so it is OK. But your variable `b` still have type with lifetime parameter `'a`, it doesn't changed after assignment.

When you return b from function, you try to convert `Box<&'a i32>` to `Box<&'static i32>`. Since `'static` is larger than `'a`, it fails.

Comment: "Bigger lifetime can be coerced to smaller one so it is OK" This is more complicated than that (variance), but true in this context.